# iOS6 up Safari File upload feature detection (bonus for iOS9)

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

Given you can [upload files from your device from iOS6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) and [upload files to a service from e.g. iCloud in iOS9](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3b5yro/ios_9_allows_safari_file_upload_for_files_from/), is there a way of feature detecting this, so that iOS5 users (if there are any left!) don't see a file upload button/dialogue?

Bonus if we can differentiate between the ability to access the photos/videos on the device and the new iOS9 ability to access files from services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1:
User Modernizr

Answer 2:
Use the feature detection from Modernizr for file upload support:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/55f041ff8325ad06c136e428a3a68e940fe00737/feature-detects/forms-fileinput.js

```
function supportsFileUpload() {
  var elem = document.createElement('input');
  elem.type = 'file';
  return !elem.disabled;
}
```